# jQuery fadeIn() doesn't reach full opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, fadein, fadeout

I am calling `fadeIn(200)` and `fadeOut(200)` to show and hide a loading image on the page while any ajax scripts run on the page.

However I find that when a script takes less time than 200ms to run the element gets stuck with a partial opacity (such as 0.88) on it, presumably because the `fadeIn()` got interrupted at that point in the fade. After this, all future fades stop at that opacity, it never reaches a full opacity of `1` again.

Could this be related to the animation queue? Perhaps there's a way to force the animations to finish or somehow have opacity reset if it's interrupted?

Comment: If it stops, something else is stopping it, and you have to add that code. Generally one solves issues like this by adding `.stop(true, true)` or even jQuery's `finish()` somewhere in the animation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution this problem is to use `fadeTo()` instead of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`. This function allows you to set a specific destination opacity which seems to eliminate the issue of getting stuck half-faded.

My specific solution was to:

Replace `fadeIn(200)` with `fadeTo(200,1)`

Replace `fadeOut(200)` with `fadeTo(200,0)`